# Error while executing SQL query on database 'database': near "GROUP": syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am starting to learn SQL so I need to make some exercises. One of the exercises I just can't find out how to do it.
We've got a database with 4 tables. And in this exercise is like:
Show an overview of the brands and type of scooters that are hired by people from Almelo, living in a random street with a house number 2. An extra condition is that the total amount paid should be more than 100 euros. Also show the total amount of the contract.

I have tried much and almost got it. But now I get everytime this error (see title)

This is my query:

```
SELECT merk, type, SUM(betaald_bedrag)
FROM T_contract
INNER JOIN T_klant ON T_contract.klantnummer = T_klant.klantnummer
INNER JOIN T_betaling ON T_contract.contractnummer = T_betaling.contractnummer
WHERE plaats = "Almelo"
AND adres LIKE "% 2"
HAVING SUM(betaald_bedrag) > 100
GROUP BY T_betaling.contractnummer
```

Can you please help me to solve this?

Comment: `having` comes after `group by`

Comment: Oh wow... thanks a lot

Comment: It works! Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT merk, type, SUM(betaald_bedrag)
FROM T_contract
INNER JOIN T_klant ON T_contract.klantnummer = T_klant.klantnummer
INNER JOIN T_betaling ON T_contract.contractnummer = T_betaling.contractnummer
WHERE plaats = "Almelo"
AND adres LIKE "% 2"
GROUP BY T_betaling.contractnummer
HAVING SUM(betaald_bedrag) > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT merk, type, SUM(betaald_bedrag)
FROM T_contract INNER JOIN
     T_klant
     ON T_contract.klantnummer = T_klant.klantnummer INNER JOIN
     T_betaling
     ON T_contract.contractnummer = T_betaling.contractnummer
WHERE plaats = 'Almelo' AND
      adres LIKE '% 2'
GROUP BY merk, type
HAVING SUM(betaald_bedrag) > 100;
```

Formatting aside (which I think is important):

- The `HAVING` clause comes after `GROUP BY`.
- The standard delimiter for a string in SQL is the single quote, not the double quote.
- You should be aggregating by the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.  It is a very bad habit to `SELECT` some columns but aggregate by others.